# How to install the sims 3... starter pack?

Tags: installation, games

I've just bought the same 3 starter pack but I don't know how to install it and I want to play the same from my heart. Somebody knows how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this from Wine HQ? This will give you all the stuff about it:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9732

Also if you need to install Origin you can view this from the database:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=5834&iTestingId=9681